# ArgumentOutOfRangeException in SqlCommand

Tags: c#, sql, timer, sqlcommand

I have two timers. One of these timers retrieves data from plc and updates the related data row in a datatable. In the other timer i send that datatable as a parameter to a stored procedure. The problem is that, sometimes my sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() gives me an ArgumentOutOfRangeException. i have 128 rows in my data table. And i read 512 bytes from plc. One row represent one float value(that means 4 bytes)

I cant understand the exception ArgumentOutOfRange. The variable count fits to the row count. What is the problem. And Why am i getting this error not always but sometimes?

Here is my code

```
        void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            byte[] data = new byte[512];
            int res = dc.readManyBytes(libnodave.daveDB, 19, 0, 512, data);
            if (res == 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
                {
                    byte[] temp = new byte[] { data[(i * 4 + 3)], data[(i * 4 + 2)], data[(i * 4 + 1)], data[(i * 4)] };
                    double value = Math.Truncate(Convert.ToDouble(BitConverter.ToSingle(temp, 0)) * 100) / 100;
                    DataRow row = dtAddress.Rows[i];
                    switch (row["DataType"].ToString())
                    {
                        case "REAL":
                            DataRow[] rValues = dtValue.Select("AddressID = " + row["ID"]);
                                foreach (DataRow rValue in rValues)
                                {
                                    rValue["Value"] = value;
                                    rValue["LastUpdate"] = DateTime.Now;
                                }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
       }

    void timer2_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlCommand crudValues = new SqlCommand("dbo.crudValues", connection))
        {
            crudValues.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter param = crudValues.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tblValue", dtValue);
            param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;

            crudValues.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

--SQL Stored Procedure

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[crudValues]
    @tblValue as dbo.tblValue READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE tblValue SET tblValue.Value = t.Value, tblValue.LastUpdate = t.LastUpdate FROM tblValue INNER JOIN @tblValue t ON tblValue.ID = t.ID
END
```

Stack Trace ;

```
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteRPC(_SqlRPC[] rpcArray, Int32 timeout, Boolean inSchema, SqlNotificationRequest notificationRequest, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isCommandProc, Boolean sync, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 startRpc, Int32 startParam)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at GazMotoruPLCScanner.Program.timer2_Elapsed(Object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) in d:\Projeler\TRES ENERJİ\GazMotoruPLCScanner\Program.cs:line 106
   at System.Timers.Timer.MyTimerCallback(Object state)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post the exception's message?

Comment: @mainvoid the exception message is `index was out of range. must be nonnegative and less than the size of the collection` And i also put the stored procedure to my question

Comment: Can the reason be the way i fill the datatable? I fill it via SqlDataAdapter. and i wrapped that dataadapter into a sqlcommandbuilder.

Comment: Are you sure the exception is thrown by the ExecuteNonQuery method?

Comment: yes i am definitely sure

Comment: Is it possible that both timers fire at the same time? Could it be that you are changing the contents of your `DataTable` while it is being sent to the database by another timer handler? I don't see any handling of this concurrency in your code.

Comment: Yes both timers have the same interval. But how can i handle that if the problem is that?

Comment: @MOD, Add the name of the user in the comment if you want him to receive a notification about your comment. I've added an answer with the example of using Mutexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is really caused by simultaneous processing of the same `DataTable` object by two threads, then one possible solution is to use [Mutex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex(v=vs.110).aspx) to sync two threads.

> When two or more threads need to access a shared resource at the same
>   time, the system needs a synchronization mechanism to ensure that only
>   one thread at a time uses the resource. Mutex is a synchronization
>   primitive that grants exclusive access to the shared resource to only
>   one thread. If a thread acquires a mutex, the second thread that wants
>   to acquire that mutex is suspended until the first thread releases the
>   mutex.

In your case first event handler adds elements to the `DataTable` and second event handler sends this `DataTable` to the stored procedure. If this object is changed while `RunExecuteReader` tries to read rows from it anything can happen.

Create one instance of the Mutex class that could be accessed from both `timer1_Elapsed()` and `timer2_Elapsed()`.

```
private static Mutex mut = new Mutex();
```

Your timer event handlers may look like this:

```
void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    int iMaxWaitMSec = 10000;
    if (mut.WaitOne(iMaxWaitMSec))
    {
        try
        {
            // Populate DataTable
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            mut.ReleaseMutex();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // we waited longer than iMaxWaitMSec milliseconds
        // in an attempt to lock the mutex
        // skip this timer event
        // we'll retry next time
    }
}
```

.

```
void timer2_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    int iMaxWaitMSec = 10000;
    if (mut.WaitOne(iMaxWaitMSec))
    {
        try
        {
            // Send DataTable to the database
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            mut.ReleaseMutex();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // we waited longer than iMaxWaitMSec milliseconds
        // in an attempt to lock the mutex
        // skip this timer event
        // we'll retry next time
    }
}
```

Check for syntax errors. Set the timeout to some appropriate value. Add proper processing of the situation when it takes too long to acquire the mutex.

Result of this approach would be that two blocks of code in `timer1_Elapsed()` and `timer2_Elapsed()` inside the `if (mut.WaitOne(iMaxWaitMSec))` would never run simultaneously.

If you have some extra code that doesn't touch the shared `DataTable` and you don't want that code to be blocked waiting for the second event handler you can put it outside the `if (mut.WaitOne(iMaxWaitMSec))` block.

**Update**

Based on your comments, here are my thoughts on how I would arrange the whole program.

The main goal is to minimize the time when two threads may be waiting for each other.

1) Make sure that you use multi-threaded timers: `System.Timers.Timer` or `System.Threading.Timer`, not the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

I want the timer event handler to run on a separate thread.

> If processing of the Elapsed event lasts longer than Interval, the
>   event might be raised again on another ThreadPool thread.

So, have a flag that indicates that event is being processed and check it. I don't think that you would want to call your stored procedure again while the previous attempt to call it hasn't finished yet.

2) Have a structure in memory that would hold a queue with your data.
First timer would periodically read data from PLC and append data to the end of the queue. Second timer would periodically check the queue and pick pending data from the beginning of the queue.
There is a class [`Queue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c(v=vs.110).aspx). Ideally it should be able to quickly append element to its end and quickly remove element from the beginning. In .NET 4 there is [`ConcurrentQueue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx), which means that you don't need explicit Mutexes.

If inserting of the data into the database suddenly becomes slow (i.e., network is down) the queue would grow and contain several elements. It is up to you to decide what you'd like to do in this case - discard extra elements, or still try to insert all of them.

3) Mutex should be used to guard only against simultaneous access to this "queue" object to minimize waiting.

```
// somewhere in the main program
Queue<DataTable> MainQueue = new Queue<DataTable>();
// or in .NET 4
ConcurrentQueue<DataTable> MainConcurrentQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<DataTable>();
```

...

```
void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // read data from PLC
    // parse, process the data
    // create a **new** instance of the DataTable object
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    // and fill it with your data

    // append the new DataTable object to the queue
    mut.WaitOne();
    try
    {
        MainQueue.Enqueue(dt);
    }
    catch { }
    finally
    {
        mut.ReleaseMutex();
    }

    // or in .NET4 simply
    MainConcurrentQueue.Enqueue(dt);
}
```

...

```
void timer2_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = null;

    mut.WaitOne();
    try
    {
        dt = MainQueue.Dequeue();
    }
    catch { }
    finally
    {
        mut.ReleaseMutex();
    }

    // or in .NET4 simply
    dt = MainConcurrentQueue.Dequeue();

    // Send DataTable to the database

    // TODO: add checks for empty queue
    // TODO: add checks for long queue 
    // and send all or some of the accumulated elements to the DB
}
```

Comment: @MOD, Actually, if both timers have the same interval... Why do you need two timers in the first place? If you can put all your code in a single timer event you will not need to sync two event handlers.

Comment: I dont want my updating datatable retard my storing to sql. And i can put update datatable codes into an event that is uncertain to fire

Comment: If I understood your comment correctly, you want two timers and two events, because you want that your saving of the data into the database doesn't interfere with reading of the data from the PLC. In other words, you want to read data from PLC every NN seconds no matter what. Saving this data into database takes some time and it is unpredictable how long it takes, so you put that step in a separate timer. Correct? If yes, then you'd better adjust the layout of your program. Using mutexes as I described make the code work as if both event handlers were merged into one - it's not what you want.

Comment: Yes. It is correct. How should i adjust the layout of my program then?

Comment: I"ve added to the answer a general idea how to use a Queue.